# Creating Views programmatically iPhone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to get started with UI programming in iOS, my first mobile application I mainly used story boards so going forward I would like my UI's to be more flexible. I have followed a couple tutorials online, word for word and line by line, I still can not get my views and subviews to show up when running the Xcode Simulator. I created a Single View Application with one viewController. Here is my code in my "ViewController.h" and "ViewController.m" file. What am I doing wrong here folks? My simulator is not displaying anything and according to the tutorials I have been following it should be.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property(strong, nonatomic) UILabel *label1;
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIButton *someButton;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // Create the label
    self.label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 25)];
    self.label1.text = @"I am a label";

    // Create the button
    self.someButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.someButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 37);
    [self.someButton setTitle:@"Example Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // Add them to the main view
    [self.view addSubview:self.label1];
    [self.view addSubview:self.someButton];
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you Assign `ViewController` class in Storyboard for your controller?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project without the storyboard and put following code, it will work..

```
UILabel *testLabel;
testLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
testLabel.text=@"Hello World!";
testLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 37);
[self.view addSubview:testLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your code is working fine in my xcode i created new single view based application and deleted the storyboard and copy pasted your code

[image: I am able to see the label and Button]

Comment: I did not delete the storyboard from my project, could that be the issue?

Comment: actually I just tried deleting the storyboard and it still did not make a difference

Comment: would you mind posting all the classes in your project's code on a github gist? It would also be great if you could tell me what simulator you are running (like iPhone retina 3.5 or 4)

Comment: even if u don't delete it it is working..Again create new project with single view based application and try.

Comment: Well, I won't be able to sorry.. and i am running on iphone retina 4 64 bit. xcode 5 gm version

Comment: Add NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__); in your viewDidLoad and check your console whether you are able to see viewcontroller viewDidLoad or not ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45966/discussion-between-ideveloper-and-aybaybay)

Answer (score 0):

When you programmatically create a UIView, UIButton or UILable, there aren't any layout constraints defined. You have to add them manually. If you do have some layoutconstraints configured for a certain view, they can be removed like so:

```
[view removeConstraints:view.constraints]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are showing the ViewController first.